# Caml Query strange behavior

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, caml

I have a problem and asking for help so any comments will be very valuable to me.

**Structure**

I have a List MAIN LIST:

**WorkshopResults**

| Title | Participant (Lookup) | Workshop (Lookup) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1234 | 1234 |
| Second | 123 | 1235 |

**Participant  > List name for Lookup**

| Title | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1234 |
| Second | 1235 |

**Worshop > List name for Lookup**

| Title | TestUniqueNumber |
| --- | --- |
| First | ABCD1 |
| Second | ABCD2 |

The problem is that I am lost on building the Caml Query to get:

From **Participant** (Title, FisrtName)
From **Workshop** (Title, TestUniqueNumber)

I do not know if there is a problem the **list** name is equal to **lookup field** name

I think I will need to project the fields in order to **LEFT JOIN**

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you to all that spend time reading my post.

Here are my conclusions.

1. This site collection is a result from a on premise migration;
2. One thing that keep my eyes, was I have exactly the same number of records in all lists.

The problems:

Who migrated don’t keep in mind the items IDs, so all lookups query wrong information relative to other lists.

Even with the same records, there are duplicates and missing items.

The content types are in the wrong order.

Finally of course the Caml Query results are wrong. The scope of this post was just to double check what I was missing.

Thanks to all